# how to resolve this Error in my json file

Tags: node.js, json

I successfully fetched data from JSON placeholder API but am finding it difficult writing the fetched data to the a file I created. I don't know where I might be wrong in my code. I got the data correctly when I logged it in the terminal but it appeared `[object Object]` in the txt file I created. please, look at my code and tell me where am wrong.

```
    const fetchData = fetch(url)
        fetchData.then(response => {
           return response.json()
    })
    .then(result => {

//writing to the txt file but got [object obect] as the output instead of the actual result

       fs.writeFile('./task/posts.txt', result, (err) => {
           if(err) throw err
           console.log(result)
        })
     
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the results in string and write it to the file :

```
const fetchData = fetch(url)
        fetchData.then(response => {
           return response.json()
    })
    .then(result => {

//writing to the txt file but got [object object] as the output instead of the actual result

       fs.writeFile('./task/posts.txt', JSON.stringify(result), (err) => {
           if(err) throw err
           console.log(result)
        })
     
    })
```